# d3.js - logarithmic scale with minus and zero in range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've built a timeline with following axis using d3.

```
        var width = 900,
        padding = 30;

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0,0 ])   
                    .range([0, 0]);   

        var xScale = d3.scale.genericLog()
                    .domain([-15e9,15e9])        
                    .range([(padding/2), width - padding * 2]).nice();
```

for `d3.scale.genericLog()` I've used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322651/how-to-avoid-log-zero-in-graph-using-d3-js/13228478#13228478). And also tested with my range in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27Afb/).

Anyhow I've to accommodate this range in logarithmic scale. The issue is minus and zero in a range.

**How do I accommodate the range of -15e9 to 15e9 in logarithmic scale of d3.js using backbone ?????**

***using d3.js 3.2.7***

Comment: Negative numbers do not have logs. Did you mean `15e-9`?

Comment: throws me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function scale(x) {
                    return logScale(linearScale(x));
                } has no method 'copy'`

Comment: [Please check this](http://jsfiddle.net/27Afb/)- @torazaburo

Comment: Check it for what? No fiddle can define logs for negative numbers.

Comment: Please find below the logic. I was confused so I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't take the log of a number <=0 (see this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207660/value-of-logarithm-of-negative-number) if you want more detail). You will have to consider using a different scaling system or transforming your data so that all the values are > 0.**

Without knowing what data you are plotting, I can't be sure if this suggestion will be appropriate, but one hack would be to draw 2 graphs, side by side. The chart on the right is simple and would contain x values running from your smallest positive value to 15E9. The chart on the left would have an x scale running from -15E9 to a value close to zero, but when you scale it in d3 you'd have to use a scale domain from +15E9 to the absolute value of your smallest negative value (i.e. the negative value closest to zero). When passing in your negative x values to the scaling function you will also have to take the absolute value of them, so that it doesn't throw an error. The messy bit about this is as the data crosses from negative to positive as the x-axis won't truly represent what is going on here; the end user must be fully aware of what is going on so that the data is not misinterpreted.

**UPDATE**

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ninjaPixel/CY5Dg/) for a working fiddle.

For pedagogy I have split the data set into 2; one with positive x values (from 1 to 1000) and one with negative x values (from -1 to -1000). In essence, the important bit of the codes is the `xScaleLeft` and `xScaleRight` functions, which scale to the left and right side of the svg. The negative half of the data is mapped onto the svg using the `xScaleLeft` function and the positive half of the data is mapped onto the svg using the `xScaleRight` function. I have also made a gap between the 2 charts, to make it clear that the x-axis is not continuous.

```
var xScaleLeft = d3.scale.log()
   .domain([1, 1000])
   .range([(width/2) - margin.middle, 0]);

var xScaleRight = d3.scale.log()
   .domain([1, 1000])
   .range([(width/2) + margin.middle, width]);
```

When plotting values for the negative dataset, we also need to take the absolute value:

```
var lineLeft = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return xScaleLeft(Math.abs(d.x)); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScaleBoth(d.y); });
```

[image: plotting negative log values in d3]

Comment: Ok. Yeah got that point. But is there any way I can avoid 0(zero). As -(minus) works in `d3.scale.log().clamp(true).domain([]).range([]).nice()`.

Comment: Yeah it's a very good idea. Could you please explain me in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STMLv/) ???- @ninjaPixel

Comment: Thanks @ninjaPixel. I will try and let you know.-@ninjaPixel