# D3.js - Log scale starting at zero

Tags: d3.js

I am plotting a y axis which should be defined in log scale. The range is from 0 to 1000.

If I try,

```
var yScale = d3.scale.log().domain([0, 1000]).range([height, 0]);
d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
```

Then only 0.01 is shown in the y axis. According to the d3 documentation, log scale range cannot have zero.

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228478/690567, but using the scale in the axis throws error.

Is there any other way plot this range (0 to 1000) in y axis?

Comment: The log of 0 is not defined. You cannot have 0 (or any negative numbers) when using a log scale.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use a differeny scale which does not not have zero but map the values back to range 0-1000? I tried the example given in the stack over flow link given above. But it didnt work.

Comment: You could use a linear scale.